# Handle multiple IO errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, ioerror

I have several IO operation that I carry out on class init but they often fail with IOError. What I would like to do is delay a few hundred ms and try again until success or some defined timeout. How can I make sure each individual command succeeds before continuing/ending the loop? I assume there is a better way than an if statement for each item and a counter to check if all commands succeeded.

My current code below often fails with IOError and hangs the rest of the application.

```
   def __init__(self):
      print("Pressure init.")
      self.readCoefficients()

   def readCoefficients(self):
      global a0_MSB;
      global a0_LSB;
      global b1_MSB;
      global b1_LSB;
      global b2_MSB;
      global b2_LSB;
      global c12_MSB;
      global c12_LSB;

      a0_MSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_MSB+0);
      a0_LSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_LSB+0);

      b1_MSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_MSB+0);
      b1_LSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_LSB+0);

      b2_MSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_MSB+0);
      b2_LSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_LSB+0);

      c12_MSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_MSB+0);
      c12_LSB = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_LSB+0);
```

Comment: As a point of style, is there a reason you are using all those global variables inside your class?  Part of the beauty of the class is it can store all the data it needs as well, and you can just access those variables from the class itself, i.e. `a = class_instance.a0_MSB`.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to change it yet (it wasn't a class before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK for you that all the files are read one after the other, you can use a simple function.

```py
import time

# ...

def readCoefficients(self):
    global a0_MSB;
    global a0_LSB;
    global b1_MSB;
    global b1_LSB;
    global b2_MSB;
    global b2_LSB;
    global c12_MSB;
    global c12_LSB;

    max_retries = 15

    a0_MSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_MSB+0, max_retries)
    a0_LSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_LSB+0, max_retries)

    b1_MSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_MSB+0, max_retries)
    b1_LSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_LSB+0, max_retries)

    b2_MSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_MSB+0, max_retries)
    b2_LSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_LSB+0, max_retries)

    c12_MSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_MSB+0, max_retries)
    c12_LSB = self.readretry(Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_LSB+0, max_retries)

    def readretry(self, address, max_retries):
        for i in range(max_retries):
            try:
                return Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(
                    Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,
                    address
                )
            except IOError as e:
                # print(e)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            raise IOError("Reading failed after multiple tries")
```

Note: You should not use globals, most specially in classes.

Comment: Will the for loop only end after retries counter is reached or am I misunderstanding something? Globals will be removed in favour of self.somevar

Comment: The for loop will be broken by the return instruction if the read succeeds. I will change `retries` to `max_retries` for better understanding.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't realise function is called for each item.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to retry each one of those last 8 lines independently or as a group? If independently you will want to make a little helper function:

```
def retry_function(tries, function, *args, **kwargs):
    for try in range(tries):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except IOError as e:
            time.sleep(.005)
    raise e   # will be the last error from inside the loop. be sure tries is at least 1 or this will be undefined!
```

Then call it like this:

```
a0_MSB = retry_function(5, Pressure.bus.read_byte_data, Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_MSB+0)
```

If not independently but as a group, you probably *still* want this helper function. But you'll have to rewrite it to handle a list of functions/arguments, or pass in another custom function

Comment: Normally if the first fails the rest will not be executed so as a group would be fine but individual is probably better anyway. In your example, how would I know when all items succeeded? It seems to me the loop would only end when "tries" is finite and not when all command run successfully.

Comment: if it succeeds, it returns with the value returned from function. i did notice an issue though where if it runs out of tries, it doesn't actually raise the exception. I edited my answer with an extra line to raise the internal exception at the end of the for loop

Comment: When the read is successful, the function returns the result (the read bytes in this example) and this breaks the for loop. If the for loop reaches its end (tries are exceeded), it raises an exception (see update of post).

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. this code tries to read all addresses, and saves the one that failed. Then waits a little and retries all the addresses that failed until all addresses have been read properly or the number of allowed retries exceeded.

```py
def readCoefficients(self):
    (
        a0_MSB, a0_LSB,
        b1_MSB, b1_LSB,
        b2_MSB, b2_LSB,
        c12_MSB, c12_LSB) = self.mio_read(15,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_MSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_A0_COEFF_LSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_MSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B1_COEFF_LSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_MSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_B2_COEFF_LSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_MSB+0,
            Pressure.MPL115A2_REGISTER_C12_COEFF_LSB+0
    )

def mio_read(self, max_retries, *addresses):
    # Create storage for results
    results = [None] * len(addresses)
    # Keep track of the index of a particular address in the list of results
    ios = list(enumerate(addresses))
    for i in range(max_retries):
        failedios = []
        for index, address in ios:
            try:
                results[index] = Pressure.bus.read_byte_data(
                    Pressure.MPL115A2_ADDRESS,
                    address
                )
            except IOError as e:
                # Place address in the queue for the next round
                failedios.append((index, address))
        # If all succeeded
        if len(failedios) == 0:
            return results
        # Time may be reduced as so was spent checking other addresses
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ios = failedios
    else:
        raise IOError(",".join((addr for ind, addr in failedios)))
```

Comment: Looks a bit overcomplicated to me :)